# How to create a mesh in any colour with a skin what is looking like absolute the same from any view, what is free from any effects?

Tags: mesh, texturing, color, grease-pencil, effects

I tried to make a good question, but maybe that didn't work well enough, but I'm sure after this explanation everybody will understand what I would like to see:

After I open a general project I use the default cube. I go to its material properties, click *Use Nodes*, change the colour to black, I set metallic and roughness values to 1 and set specular to 0. In render and in an exported FBX I see a cube, which is "fully black", but keep its form. I remembered another explanation: When I convert a mesh object, for example a human body to grease pencil, I get 2 layers. Now the important thing for me is the white/grey one. So I would like to make meshes which are looking like the black cube or the "human body's" white/grey layer, but in any colour. Now I can't, because when I change the colour, the result is not what it is in the two written examples. I hope there is a solution. Thanks your answers in advance!